# DIscord bot can't edit message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord, disnake

I am having issues with fetching a message by id. It's kinda weird that I can't edit the message I just sent.

I get the error:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

Code to replicate the error:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.commands import slash_command

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @slash_command(name='test', description='')
    async def test(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"The message I want to get by id"
        )
        msg = await ctx.respond(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
        msg_id = msg.id

        await asyncio.sleep(2)

        channel = self.bot.get_channel(ctx.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
        new_embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"new message test"
        )
        await message.edit(embed=new_embed)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

I specifically need to get channel and then fetch message by its id. I seems unlogical, but I need it.

Comment: It's possible that your bot simply doesn't have permission to view the channel's history. If that is the case, you need to go into your server's settings and give the bot permission. Please share the entire traceback of the error; there are several lines here which could raise the `NotFound` error.

Comment: Why don't you `await msg.edit(embed=new_embed)` ? There is no need to fetch your message like this, as you already have the message object from your `msg` variable.

Comment: Why are you fetching the message if you already have the message object?

Comment: @Paul Response returns an interaction which can't be edited directly. See [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.edit_original_message)

Comment: @BlueRobin he doesn't appear to be using pycord, despite the tags on the post

Comment: @Paul That does look like pycord because of the way slash commands and cogs are set up

Comment: @Paul I am actually using pycord

Comment: @BlueRobin I am fetching the message here because this is a test code to replicate the problem, in my normal program I get message id from json file, and I need to fetch this message and then edit it in another function.
So I guesss it's not possible?

Comment: @Gaberocksall I have all the right permissions

Comment: @syrok I don't believe you can edit on a fetched messageable. Instead, use the previous message object that you used to send the command in the first place

Comment: Never mind, I believe you can edit the message from that. I believe the ID you're passing is incorrect. `msg.id` might be returning none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you're passing into `channel.fetch_message` is incorrect.

The error is on the following line in your code:

```
msg_id = msg.id
```

Instead of getting the message ID, this is getting the [interaction ID](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.id). The `msg` variable that you store `ctx.respond`'s return value is actually an [interaction object](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction), and not a messageable. Instead, get the [`msg.message.id`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.message) which would be:

```py
msg_id = msg.message.id
```